# define value with comma through cmake

Tags: csv, cmake, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I used to have a define like this:

```
#define MY_CLSID {0xc9955517, 0x6ca4, 0x439f, {0x86, 0xb7, 0xdd, 0xc5, 0xb6, 0x45, 0xe7, 0x6c}}
```

now I want to do this through cmake, but I have failed so far. Anyone knows how to do that?

P.S.: That was my try:

```
add_definitions(/D MY_CLSID={0x87f8774f,0xb485,0x47e2,{0xa7,0x55,0xa4,0xa,0x8a,0x5e,0x88,0x6c}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, arrowdodger's answer is correct and if you have only a few of those defines, I would recommend it as well. In case of lots of (more complex) defines, the use of [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:configure_file) can be a good alternative:

```
// In Your_CLSID.h.in
#cmakedefine {0xc9955517, 0x6ca4, 0x439f, {0x86, 0xb7, 0xdd, 0xc5, 0xb6, 0x45, 0xe7, 0x6c}}
// end of Your_CLSID.h.in
```

and generate a "Your_CLSID.h" with

```
configure_file( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Your_CLSID_Config.h.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/common/Your_CLSID.h )
```

Of course, you will have to add your binary dir to the include-directories:

```
include_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/common )
```

See also my similar answers to the following questions:

- [how-to-read-a-cmake-variable-in-c-source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900661/how-to-read-a-cmake-variable-in-c-source-code/7900862#7900862)
- [how-to-create-a-c-define-for-a-certain-target-using-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352074/how-to-create-a-c-define-for-a-certain-target-using-cmake/5353747#5353747)

Comment: Hum, I think it will not just work, it'll work better than I thought. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with quotes:

```
add_definitions(
  /D MY_CLSID="{0x87f8774f,0xb485,0x47e2,{0xa7,0x55,0xa4,0xa,0x8a,0x5e,0x88,0x6c}}"
)
```

Comment: Did not worked here. I'm using CMake and Visual Studio, and you?