# Fixing lib compatibility c++ mingw and postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql, mingw, soci

I am trying to use postgresql together with SOCI, building their libs with MinGW.

I ran into the following problem.

PostgreSQL defines this strcuture @ pthread.h:

```
#ifndef HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC 1
struct timespec {
    long tv_sec;
    long tv_nsec;
};
#endif /* HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC */
```

But into the compiler, there is also this structure @ timeb.h

```
#ifndef _TIMESPEC_DEFINED
#define _TIMESPEC_DEFINED
struct timespec {
    time_t  tv_sec;   /* Seconds */
    long    tv_nsec;  /* Nanoseconds */
};

struct itimerspec {
    struct timespec  it_interval;  /* Timer period */
    struct timespec  it_value;     /* Timer expiration */
};
#endif
```

This is causing duplicate declaration of timespec. My questions are:

- Can I just edit the macros at postgresql to avoid this to be declared twice?
- If so, would this **time_t** and **long** difference of **timespec.tv_spec**'s type be a problem?
- What would be a good way to fix this situation?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time_t` and `long` **could** be a problem, although I find it very unlikely. This is because `time_t` is usually defined as an alias to a `long`.

Instead of changing the macros in postgres' libraries, I would first try to define the macro passing `-D` flag to the compiler.

```
g++ -DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC -o prog file.cc
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! How can I pass these parameter to build with cmake?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352074/how-to-create-a-c-define-for-a-certain-target-using-cmake